# Cocoa interface element to add/remove fields like rules editor in Mail.app

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nspredicateeditor, nsruleeditor

What is the name of the Cocoa interface with buttons to add/remove rows?

Here is a picture of it in the mail app

[image]

Is this a standard interface or is it a custom feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you're looking for is [`NSRuleEditor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSRuleEditor_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRuleEditor). If you want something specialized for editing `NSPredicate` objects, take a look at the [`NSPredicateEditor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSPredicateEditor_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditor.html) subclass.